# AS3 is not loading crossdomain.xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have this code:

```
var advert:Loader = new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.video_src);
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.checkPolicyFile = true;
context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
advert.load(url, context);
```

For some reason there is no packet at all for the crossdomain.xml query

Also i get this error:

> Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2048: Security
>   sandbox violation: http://edomain.com/flashfile.swf?t=1413815793214
>   cannot load data from

And this is the crossdomain that should be loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using an URLLoader to download the SWF and use loadBytes on the Loader with the data returned? That way you can bypass the securityDomain check and still force it to use SecurityDomain.currentDomain (as that's what used for loadBytes and can't even be changed)

Comment: He has no level yet to answer, also his method works i just didn't marked it as answer yet i am waitng for a better solution.